# If statements comparing variables in haml producing true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have two if statements in my haml file

```
- if #{id} == 1
  %h1 #{id}

- if #{id} == 2
  %h1 #{id}
```

If I have the id 1 or 2, both come out as being true so I get printed on the page "1 1" or "2 2". How can I do a comparison against a variable value. Thank you

EDIT:
This is what I am passing to my view:

```
    render "show" , :locals => {:id => params[:id]}
```

EDIT 2:

This should produce two 1 but only produces 1 from the very last tag when id=1. So I don't know what could be the problem. Any additional thoughts?

```
- if id == 1
  %h1= id

- if id == 2
  %h1= id

%h1= id
```

ANSWER: This worked. (Needed the quotes for the string)

```
- if id == "1"
   %h1= id

- if id == "2"
   %h1= id

%h1= id
```

Comment: you dont need interpolation while comparing. `- if id == 1`

Comment: I get nothing if I do that

Comment: if you are passing type in locals check `type` like  `-if type == 1`

Comment: you are right. However I copied the wrong controller code. Sorry made additional correction above

Comment: cool, its all right np :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
- if id == "1"
  %h1= id

- if id == "2"
  %h1= id
```

Assuming you want:

```
<% if id == "1" %>
  <h1><%= id %></h1>
<% end %>

<% if id == "2" %>
  <h1><%= id %></h1>
<% end %>
```

If this doesn't work for you, the problem is elsewhere.